# Azure AD B2C, ASP.NET Mvc and JQuery Ajax - Refreshing expired token via Ajax problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I have a web application that is built using .NET 7.0 and Mvc/Razor.  This application is secured by Microsoft Identity libraries and Azure AD B2C.  I have added the `[Authorize]` attribute to the Mvc controllers and this is working perfectly.  I can log in and the pages can access the controllers correctly, and if the auth tokens expire, they are refreshed correctly, etc.

The problem comes when I try to access some of the endpoints in the mvc controllers via a JQuery Ajax call in a page.  When I make a call, and the auth tokens have expired, I see a `302` response (which is correct behaviour I believe) but then I get a `CORS error`.  But more specifically, the error that appears in the Chrome DevTools console is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxx.b2clogin.com/xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signup_signin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?<additional stuff>' (redirected from 'http://localhost:57152/<mvc controller endpoint>?callback=jQuery360002914740315700981_1669878277934&_=1669878277935') from origin 'http://localhost:57152' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I believe the way to handle this is to intercept the 302 response, change it to a 401 (unauthorized) response and then have AJAX handle the 401 by taking the user a login page.  Is this the correct approach?  If so, how do I go about intercepting the 302 response?  Because I tried to do this with a custom Authorize attribute on the controller, but the CORS error happened before the attribute could have a chance to intercept.

I've spent many hours looking for a solution to this so hopefully someone has experienced this same issue and has managed to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by doing two things ... adding some middleware to `startup.cs` and handling the JQuery method `.ajaxError`.

The middleware, which intercepts a request to work out if it has a 302 response (typical when a auth token is being refreshed) and the request is a AJAX request.  If so, change the response to a 401 unathorized.

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next.Invoke();

    // Is the response a redirect?
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status302Found)
    {
        // Is the request an AJAX request?
        if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Requested-With", out var headerValue) && headerValue == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
        }
    }
});
```

The JQuery AJAX error method checks to see if the error is a 401 error.  If so, then send the browser to the Sign In page, which will either automatically refresh the auth token, or prompt the user to sign in again.  In my example, below, I'm using a DevExpress control to let the user know the session has expired.

```js
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
    if (request.status === 401) {
        var result = DevExpress.ui.dialog.alert("<p>Your session has expired and we will attempt to log you in again.</p><p>Please note, this will refresh the page and you will lose unsaved data.</p>", "Session Expired");
        result.done(function () {
            var signInUri = '@(Url.Content("~/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn?redirectUri="))' + encodeURIComponent(location.pathname);
            location.href = signInUri;
        });
    }
});
```

This is working for me, but I'm open to solutions that handle this scenario in a more robust, elegant fashion.

Comment: I have the same issue and by now I have not found a roboust solution.